# How to set hyperparameters with a dictionary

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameters, lightgbm

```py
model = lightgbm.LGBMClassifier()  
hyperparameter_dictionary = {'boosting_type': 'goss',   'num_leaves': 25, 'n_estimators': 184, ...}
```

How do I set the model's hyperparameters with the dictionary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pass the hyperparam dictionary to the model constructor, adding `**` to the dict to pass each dict item like a kwarg param as lgbm expects it per https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.html#lightgbm.LGBMClassifier:

```
hyperparameter_dictionary = {'boosting_type': 'goss', 'num_leaves': 25, 'n_estimators': 184}
model = lightgbm.LGBMClassifier(**hyperparameter_dictionary)
```

TEST:

```
print(model)

LGBMClassifier(boosting_type='goss', ... n_estimators=184, n_jobs=-1, num_leaves=25,...)
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The sklearn BaseEstimator interface provides `get_params` and `set_params` for getting and setting hyperparameters of an estimator. LightGBM is compliant so you can do as follows:

```py
model = lightgbm.LGBMClassifier()  
hyperparameter_dictionary = {'boosting_type': 'goss',   'num_leaves': 25, 'n_estimators': 184}  
model.set_params(**hyperparameter_dictionary)
```

Comment: This is right too. I think the point that I missed was the ** 
Thanks for the help!